# Plotting aggregated data in R

Tags: r

I have an aggregated data set in R. Now I wanted to plot the data according to the two keys in the data i.e two columns.
Below is the sample data set . Grades range from 1-25 and are divided in group of 5

```
Date             Grade         price 
01/01/2012        1             50
01/01/2012        2             20
01/01/2012        3             41
01/01/2012        4             56
02/01/2012        1             78
02/01/2012        2             89
02/01/2012        3             100
02/01/2012        4             12
02/01/2012        5             0
02/01/2012        6             60

sortmax=aggregate(a$price, by=list(a$Date), FUN=max)
```

If i aggregate the price by date and using the FUN=max, I will get the maximum price of a particular day. I want to find the maximum price of a particular grade group like max price in 1-5 grade and then max price for 6-10 grade and so on for everyday . So in simple words I will have 5 values for each day. Example

```
Date            Grade      Max price 
01/01/2012       1-5            56
01/01/2012       6-10           52
01/01/2012       11-15          56
01/01/2012       15-20          78
01/01/2012       21-25          50   
02/01/2012       1-5            100
02/01/2012       6-10           110
02/01/2012       11-15          56
02/01/2012       15-20          85 
02/01/2012       21-25          25
```

How do I plot the date vs max price for each group each day , like plotting daily max price of grade 1-5 for each day and one final question is how do I plot all of these lines on a single plot with different colors . Many packages are not available for R 3.1.1 , windows Xp

Comment: In your initial example, are those individual grades, so that you want to semi-aggregate those (so all 4 of the 1/1/2012 would be in the first grade group 1-5)?

Comment: Also, are you asking how to aggregate, how to plot once you aggregate, or both?  If you want help plotting, what plot type do you prefer (or are you open to any of the three main ones)?

Comment: Ya I dont know how can i do it without using loops and I used simple line plot like I used plot(cbind(date,price),type='l') for individual grades

Comment: Perhaps you can use ggplot. Process dates properly (so that ggplot knows) and color by Grade (group by).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group your grades, create a data.frame with the relationships - easy:

```
gradeRange <- data.frame(c(rep('1-5',5),rep('6-10',5)),1:10)
```

(keep going for up to 25 of course) and give it names (Grade, Range) for example; then append it to x:

```
x$gradeRange <- gradeRange[gradeRange$Grade == x$Grade]
```

Or write it with math (based on mults. of 5):

```
x$gradeRange <- floor((x$Grade-1)/5)+1
```

(and then you can make those factor values, or just leave them 1/2/3/4/5).

Then you can use ggplot to graph them, or summarize and use lattice or plot, using gradeRange for group.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working , the gradeRange column remains empty . I aggregated it using  sortmax=aggregate(price, list(Date,cut(Grade, breaks=c(1,5,10,15,25))), max). But the problem is that 5 is included in both 1-5 and 5-10 . Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: I also plotted using ggplot  ggplot(data = sortmax, aes(x = sortmax$Date, y = (sortmax$x), colour = sortlimit$group.1)) + geom_line(aes(group = sortlimit$group.1)) + geom_point() . But I am not getting different colors for different groups